# Startapp interstitial ad will always cause an OGL context lose?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, startapp

I'm making an android app, and I want to show the typical splash screen ad once my game is loaded.
The problem I'm facing is that I run the game, it loads the textures, and then it shows the intersitial ad. When I close the ad, I have to recreate the textures, and it's quite slow...

Is there a way to prevent this or it is the expected behaviour? Will I face the same problem with other ad companies (for example admob)??

By the way I'm using OpenGL for my app as well as Startapp for the ads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've been researching this and I wasn't able to prevent texture reloading with interstitial ads using either admob and startapp.

Then I tried to use Leadbolt, and it's simply overlaying an ad in front of the app but it's not an activity, so I don't have to reload the textures.

If someone finds another ad network which works in a similar way (doesn't force texture reload) it would be great to know :P